# Form with target="_blank" behavior changed in IE 9 and 10

Tags: javascript, forms, tabs, internet-explorer-9, internet-explorer-10

I have an app that uses something like the following code to open a dynamically generated report in a new tab. (I've mocked out the parameters for the sake of a demo.)

```
function gblPDFWdw(pdf) {
    var formDiv = document.createElement("div");
    formDiv.innerHTML = "<form method=post action='" + pdf + "' target='_blank'><input type=hidden id=test name=test value='test'></form>";
    var form = formDiv.firstChild;
    document.body.appendChild(form);
    form.submit();
    form.parentNode.removeChild(form);
}
```

The `pdf` parameter us just the URL to the script that generates the PDF. The reason for the `form` manipulation is to get the parameters `POST`ed to the script rather than as `GET` parameters.

In IE 8 and below, Chrome, Firefox, etc., this will do one of two things:

1. If the browser can read PDFs (via built-in functionality or a plugin), it will open a new tab with the report, which is the desired behavior.
2. If the browser can't read PDFs, it will open the new tab, immediately close it, and download the file.

It seems that #2 has changed in IE 9 and above. It will open a new tab, but it yields only a blank screen until the user goes **back to the original tab**, clicks "Open" or "Save", and then the PDF downloads as expected. It's a very confusing interface.

I suppose one way to work around this would be to generate a temporary PDF file, and then simply window.open() to it. Are there other ways to tweak the behavior of this functionality? Or is there a recommended practice that I've not run across?

(Note: This isn't at all PDF specific; any file that the browser may download instead of display natively seems to be problematic.)

**EDIT**: Looks like I'm further behind the curve than I realized. It appears that this also occurs in IE9, and I'd never noticed as I never tried it without the PDF plugin installed or with another file type.

Interestingly, the above code works like I'd expect if I **remove** the `input` field from the form. I'm not sure why the browser would treat that any differently. Of course, in my case, I need the input to `POST` data to my script.

**EDIT 2**: Silly mistake. `input` is self-closing. Fixed.

**EDIT 3**: Here are some screenshots to better explain the issue. I'm using [this JSBin](http://jsbin.com/oxidan/3) for testing. I have an onclick event to trigger the Javascript function above.

The process starts on the first tab.

[image: First tab, before a click.]

Then, once you click the text, a new tab opens. But it's blank!

[image: Second tab, opened via click.]

And it turns out that the **original** (now hidden) tab has a message asking whether to open or save the file.

[image: The alert is on the first tab!]

Clicking "Open" or "Save" will open the file just fine. But the process is terribly confusing, and inconsistent with other browsers.

**EDIT 3**: One step forward, one back. If I use `window.open()` to create a new window, and then programmatically set the `form.target` to the name of that window, I can at least get the Open/Save message in the opened tab…though I'd much prefer it to immediately close the tab like other browsers. Worse, with that technique, the new tab no longer immediately closes. Perhaps there's another technique?

Comment: There isn't a `</input>` closing tag for an `<input>` - it's a self-contained tag. Probably not working due to malformed HTML.

Comment: @sbeliv01 Good point…silly mistake. But that didn't change the problem. Thanks, though!

Comment: Perhaps adding quotes around the attributes in the input tag would help? `<input type='hidden' id='test' name='test' value='test'>`

Comment: @sbeliv01 Nope, just tried it. I'm reasonably sure it isn't exactly a HTML validation issue. The new tab opens just fine…it's just that the Open/Save choice appears on the **previous** tab, which is now hidden.

Honestly, if there is a better way to POST data into a new tab, I'm all ears.

Comment: The new tab is *supposed* to close itself, because it's not used for the file download which is taken over by the original page. Is the target URL perhaps in a different security zone than the original page? Have you repro'd on multiple clients?

Comment: @EricLaw I'm glad someone else thinks the new tab ought to close itself—that's the behavior I see in other browsers and am looking for. And, yes, I have reproduced it on multiple clients—it was reported by a customer, and I've been able to reproduce it in the office on Windows 7 and 8.

The security zone question is interesting. That shouldn't be the case in our production app (all URLs are on the same domain), but I should do a bit of research there to make sure my jsbin example is accurate.

Comment: Who cares for compatibility bugs/inconsistencies within IE. The only reason it's there is because you can bare with it to download chrome/firefox

Comment: @DarylGill Ha! Yes, I'd tend to agree with you. Unfortunately, we haven't yet convinced our entire customer base of that. Yet. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One off-shot solution would be to detect IE and PDF plugin avaliability and then set 'target' attribute to '_self' in (>IE9 && !plugin) situation. I've found [PluginDetect](http://www.pinlady.net/PluginDetect/) which claims AdobeReader plugin detection.

All in all it is fairly ugly and unreliable method but should give result in some cases.

Comment: The real problem, though, is that this is happening with Excel files, too. (Perhaps only if Office or some ActiveX thing isn't installed? Haven't yet narrowed that down.) Thanks, though.

Comment: Of course…now that I think about it some more…I could just always force Excel files to `_self`. Interesting!

Comment: @DavidAlanHjelle: Documentation says that Acrobat is detected by ActiveX lookup it seems it is the IE way to do any plugin detection. Found this ActiveXHelper [http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/axhelper.html]

Comment: Thanks! Interestingly, I already detect the Adobe plugin for other purposes…I'll have to look into the Excel specifics more. (I'm hoping for a less hacky answer; but I'll accept yours if I don't get one.)